# How to redirect and get url params

Tags: vue.js, url, parameters

I have a head bar with a search input that is shared across the layout. I have to redirect to search page results when user enter (keyup) a term:

/search?term=blah

I'm redirecting passing the term but as long as the user continues to enter more letter/terms I can't get that data. Just the first term.

SearchForm Component:

```
this.$router.push(`/search?term=${this.term}`)
```

Search Page (nuxt)

```
mounted () {
   this.search(this.$route.query.term)
},
methods: {
    search (term) {
      axios.get(`https://api.com/search?search=${term}`)
        .then(res => (this.results = res.data))
    }
}
```

But the search method is called only when the first letter is entered because I'm using a keyup event to redirect to the search route.
How can I fix this solution to call search method on every keyup ?
Or is there a better way to solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: if my answer was helpful to you, please upvote & accept it so that it can help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something like lodash's [debounce()](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) function in order to wait until the user has (probably) finished typing before redirecting. Vue actually has a great example of this in their docs on [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers).

If you decide to include lodash in your project (it may already be included), you could do something like the following:

```
created() {
  this.debouncedSearch = _.debounce(this.search, 500)
},
methods: {
  search (term) {
    axios.get(`https://api.com/search?search=${term}`)
      .then(res => (this.results = res.data))
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  search: function(term) {
    this.debouncedSearch();
  }
}
```

Your search page would probably need its own search form/input in order to allow the user to continue to refine their search after being redirected to the search page.